# Is it not a function?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

My knowledge:The funcion must be bijective iff the function can be inversed.

The question from the book said that "Let f: R⇒R have the rule $f(x)=⌊3x⌋-1.$Find $f^{-1}(S)$ Where $s=\{0\}$.

we have $f(x)=y$,we can see that if x is $[1/3,2/3)$,then y is $0$,

that means the function is not injective,also not bijective,we cannot inverse the function,how can we get $f^{-1}$?Does the question is wrong?

Comment: I expect they mean:  Find all real numbers $x$ such that $f(x)=0$.

Comment: @lulu Why they are  using $f^{-1}$?

Comment: $f^{-1}(S)$ denote the pre-image of a set $S$ under the function $f$. The function $f$ need not be a bijection.

Comment: That's what standard notation for the pre-image of a set.

Comment: @lulu so when does $f^{-1}$ mean the inverse function or preimage of a set?

Comment: Context usually clarifies things.  Here, note that they avoid writing $f^{-1}(0)$ and instead write $f^{-1}(S)$ where $S$ is identified as a set.  Note that, in cases where the function is invertible and $S$ contains only a single element from the range, the two definitions coincide.

Comment: If $g^{-1}$ is an inverse function then $g^{-1}(S)$ is the preimage of a set under the function $g$. I suppose it was convenient to use the notation as a notation for preimage whether or not the function actually had an inverse. Consider it one of those odd notations such as $\sin^2(x)$ which has been taken to mean $(\sin x)^2$ rather than the more logical $\sin(\sin x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f:A \to B$ is a function and $ S \subseteq B$, then, by definition(!)

$$f^{-1}(S):= \{x \in A: f(x) \in S\}.$$

If $S=\{0\}$, then

$$f^{-1}(S)= \{x \in A: f(x) =0\}.$$

Comment: when does f−1 mean the inverse function or preimage of a set?Thanks

Comment: Lee, it depends on context. There isn't always a hard rule for one vs the other.